# Whenever i open a terminal, is there a script to make it open but it shows as a background app?

Tags: python, gnome-terminal

I am making a script that finds unwanted items and hiding the terminal seems better to do.

Answer (score 1):

every time you open a terminal the ~/.bashrc script is run

you can add any scripting you want in there (at the end typically) and it will run every time a terminal is opened

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make your python script not open a terminal window when you run it, then I believe what you do is replace the `.py` file extension with `.pyw` on your main script, this tells python that you do not need the terminal.

I believe there are also other ways of doing this, so if this doesn't work for you, or if this isn't what you wanted, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks, by chance could you send a download link for that? thank you.